# C# - Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible

Tags: visual-c++, pinvoke, dllimport

I am trying to use the VC++ (2003) dll in C# (2010)
    When am calling the method of dll from c# am getting this error
    "Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible"

```
I am returning the structure from VC++
Code:
struct SLFData
{
public:
char ByLat[10];
char ByLong[10];
};

And I am marshalling in C# 
Code:
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct SLFData
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        public char[] ByLat;     
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        public char[] ByLong;
    };
```

Yet again I get the same error!
What am I missing here?
Can anybody help me Plzz

Comment: "char" is 2 bytes in C#, try "byte" instead.

Comment: It is complaining about your [DllImport] declaration, we can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you are using the struct as a return value. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx) says:

> Structures that are returned from platform invoke calls must be blittable types. Platform invoke does not support non-blittable structures as return types.

Your struct is not blittable. So you cannot use it as a function return type.

The simplest way to proceed is to return the struct via a parameter of the function. Change the C++ function to accept a parameter of type `SLFData*` and have the caller pass in the address of a struct which the C++ function populates. On the C# side you pass the struct as an `out` parameter.

FWIW, your struct declaration is wrong. For a start C# `char` is two bytes wide. It's best done like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SLFData
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public string ByLat;     
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public string ByLong;
};
```

Comment: I cannot modify the VC++ code. Replacing char[] by string works me. Thanks @David