# Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible .net framework 4.8

Tags: c#, marshalling, dllimport

I have C dll function which returns struct with fixed array size

```c
const int SIZE = 5;

typedef struct Foo{
    uint8_t data[SIZE];
} Foo;

DLL_EXPORT Foo bar(){
    Foo f;
    //fill f
    return f;
}
```

On C# side I have

```cs
struct Foo{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
    byte[] data;
}

[DllImport(...)]
static extern Foo bar();
```

This code works fine if I use .Net 5.0, but fails with exception from a title if I use .Net Framework 4.8.

Why is this code works fine on .Net 5.0 and is there a possible free'd memory access after return from a C function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201996/c-sharp-methods-type-signature-is-not-pinvoke-compatible)

Comment: Not quite, documentations says, that "one-dimentional arrays of blittable primitive types are also blittable types". Byte is blittable type.

Comment: I changed UnmanagedType.ByValArray to fixed array declaration and unsafe struct declaration. It worked, but I don't feel like I got the idea